# Ranking genes within GSEA

Tags: p-value, ranking, bioinformatics, combining-p-values

I know you can rank genes by p-/q-value, or by log2 fold change. But can you combine the two methods somehow?

I have read about combining fold change and p-value [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3957066/) but what is one advantage and one disadvantage of using this ranking method?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the classic paper explaining Gene Set Expression Analysis (GSEA) ([Reference 1](https://www.pnas.org/doi/epdf/10.1073/pnas.0506580102)) . Given two classes of samples (representing 2 phenotypes, 2 experimental treatments, etc.), GSEA first places *all* genes into a ranked numeric list *L*, based on differential expression between the two classes, and then determines whether a pre-defined set of genes *S* tends to be found at the extremes of that list.

> The gene sets are defined based on prior biological knowledge, e.g., published information about biochemical pathways or coexpression in previous experiments. The goal of GSEA is to determine whether members of a gene set *S* tend to occur toward the top (or bottom) of the list *L*, in which case the gene set is correlated with the phenotypic class distinction.

That's different from other "over-representation" approaches that use only a *subset* of genes in the list *L*, selected as highly or poorly expressed based on some cutoff criterion. That cutoff criterion is typically based on some estimate of "statistical significance" like a false discovery rate. GSEA is thus less concerned with issues of "statistical significance" of differential expression of individual genes than those other approaches.

Given the list *L*, the process continues:

> We calculate an enrichment score (*ES*) that reflects the degree to which a set *S* is overrepresented at the extremes (top or bottom) of the entire ranked list *L*. The score is calculated by walking down the list *L*, increasing a running-sum statistic when we encounter a gene in *S* and decreasing it when we encounter genes not in *S*. *The magnitude of the increment depends on the correlation of the gene with the phenotype.* The enrichment score is the maximum deviation from zero encountered in the random walk; it corresponds to a weighted Kolmogorov–Smirnov-like statistic. (Emphasis added)

The emphasized sentence is a major distinction from an earlier version of GSEA, in which equal weights were used at each step.

> In the original implementation, the running-sum statistic used equal weights at every step, which yielded high scores for sets clustered near the middle of the ranked list (Fig. 2 and Table 1). These sets do not represent biologically relevant correlation with the phenotype. We addressed this issue by weighting the steps according to each gene’s correlation with a phenotype.

For the weights:

> Genes are ranked based on the correlation between their expression and the class distinction by using any suitable metric.

So the question is: what is a suitable metric for ranking the gene list *L* and weighting the GSEA running sum?

The paper linked by the OP ([Reference 2](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3957066/)) seems focused on identifying "differentially expressed" genes, which is *not* required for GSEA. Thus that paper's emphasis on the area under the receiver operating characteristic curve (AUC) as a metric for evaluating different ranking methods seems a bit misplaced, if your primary interest is in GSEA with its ranked list of *all* genes.

A moderated *t*-statistic on log-transformed expression values (e.g., the empirical Bayes or "treat" methods provided by the Bioconductor [`limma` package](https://doi.org/doi:10.18129/B9.bioc.limma)) provides a useful way to rank all genes for GSEA. That tends to minimize over-ranking of genes based on their individual *t*-statistics and thus minimizes the "small fold change, small variance" problem noted in Reference 2. If you are worried about the "large fold change, large variance" problem noted in that reference, you could consider just using log-fold changes as the metric. If those are problems for just a few genes in a gene set *S*, your choice of ranking metric might not matter much at all. That's a strength of GSEA with its emphasis on the entire set of gene-expression values.

---

Ref. 1. [Subramanian et al., PNAS 102: 15545–15550, 2005](https://www.pnas.org/doi/epdf/10.1073/pnas.0506580102).

Ref. 2. [Xiao et al., Bioinformatics 30: 801–807, 2014](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3957066/)